# Adding multiple content CSS files to CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

How can I use more than 1 css file as content CSS with CKEditor? I already added bootstrap css in the config.

```
config.contentsCss = '/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Our designer created a 2nd css to customize some stuff and I also need to add that css file to CKEditor.

I tried variations below, but no success so far:

```
config.contentsCss = '/css/bootstrap.min.css', '/css/styles.css';
config.contentsCss = '/css/bootstrap.min.css, /css/styles.css';
```

I am using v 4.1.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) documentation is absolutely clear about this. This setting accepts a string or an array of strings. Like this:

```
config.contentsCss = [ '/css/mysitestyles.css', '/css/anotherfile.css' ];
```

Comment: I'll add that you can also provide directly a css string, and also mix css path / inline css in the contentCss array. (not in the doc)